# How to build Python 2.6.8 with zlib on Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Tags: python, compilation, makefile, zlib, python-2.6

Missing `zlib` is common problem for Python 2.6, as I know.

I have `zlib1g-dev` installed, and I also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1759873&p=10830295#post10830295) solution - and still not succeed.

Also I've tried `./configure --with-libs=usr/include/zlib.h` and got:

```
libpython2.6.a /usr/include/zlib.h -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
```

Does somebody else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

To get zlib support, you need to set some flags when compiling python as stated here.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1759873&p=10830295#post10830295

For ssl support, you will need to apply a patch as discussed here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976837